# vector is loosing mat4 information

Tags: c++, opengl, vector

I have a List of Entities I want to update and than render. For updating:

Variable:

```
std::vector<Entity> entityList;
```

function:

```
void EntityController::update(){
    for(Entity e : entityList){        
        e.update();
    }
}
```

and the update function for the entity

```
void Entity::update(){

glm::mat4 trans = glm::mat4();
trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(50.0f,0.0f,50.0f));
trans = glm::scale(trans, glm::vec3(21.0,21.0,21.0));

modelMatrix = trans;
}
```

My problem here is, that the model matrix actually works. I can find all my information when I take a look at it (Debugging mode XCode), as long as I am in the class entity.

But When I am out of that class, the information in the model matrix is the identity matrix again. somehow he does not save, or update the information :S

Comment: The most likely cause is that you are modifying a copy, not the original object.

Comment: That's my guess. It will be better if you can post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added a little bit in the code. somehow I forgot the for each loop. But I don't know what information more could be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're `update()`ing `Entity` *copies* with your current range `for`:

```
for(Entity e : entityList)
          ^ huh?
```

You probably wanted references:

```
for(Entity& e : entityList)
          ^ important
```

Comment: thank you, didn't know that :S